# Extended a vector field over a fibre to a vertical vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let's say $F: M \rightarrow N$ is a smooth submersion between manifolds. Then each fiber of $F$ is a properly embedded submanifold. If $S$ is such a fiber, and I take some vector field $D \in \Gamma(TS)$, then I know I can extend $D$ to a smooth vector field on $M$, say $\tilde{D}$. But can I always do this in a way so that $\tilde{D}$ is a vertical vector field (i.e., tangent to the fibers of $F$)?

Comment: Can you do this for the canonical submersion $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $m\ge n$? Then use rank theorem and a bump function.